# C# add selected row from one DatagridView to another and with second select add + quantity

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two DatagridViews in Windowsform c# , in one I have selected all my products(Dgtv_artikelbestellung)  from Database and dipslayed there.

the other one is for ordered product (dgv_bestellteArtikel,
I want if I click one the sign "+" it adds that selected row to the other DataGridView and if I double click on the same selected row it should then in the 2nd Datagridview ++1 in columns "Menge"Quantity. So far I can add the rows but that if I second time add the same product it doesn't add quantity.
How can I achive that ? Can someome please help ?
here how it looks like :
[Datagridview demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OXGB.png)
And here the code I have for it.

```
private void Dgtv_artikelbestellung_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            string tttts = "";
            bool gefunden = false;
            if (Dgtv_artikelbestellung.Rows.Count > 0 && Dgtv_artikelbestellung.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Dgtv_artikelbestellung.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
                {
                    int indexvar = dgv_bestellteArtikel.Rows.Add();
                    dgv_bestellteArtikel.Rows[indexvar].Cells[0].Value = Dgtv_artikelbestellung.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    dgv_bestellteArtikel.Rows[indexvar].Cells[1].Value = Dgtv_artikelbestellung.SelectedRows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    dgv_bestellteArtikel.Rows[indexvar].Cells["Menge"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dgv_bestellteArtikel.Rows[indexvar].Cells["Menge"].Value) + 1;
                    tttts=dgv_bestellteArtikel.Rows[indexvar].Cells["Menge"].Value.ToString();

                    if(tttts != null && tttts.ToString()== tttts)
                    {
                        gefunden = true;
                    }
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: Before the code executes the line… `int indexvar = dgv_bestellteArtikel.Rows.Add();` … the code should check to see if the selected item is already in the second grid. If it is… then you do not want to “add” a new row, you want to increment the existing one. Also I have ask, since `tttts` is a string… when would `tttts.ToString()== tttts` ever be false?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the cell's value is changed but DatagridView control is not updated. Try to call [EndInit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.endedit?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#overloads) method.

Comment: Yes the values changes so every time I Click it adds a 1 to the quantity but it also create a new row in the 2nd Datagridview. How can I make it that for first click ( or if it doesn’t exist already in the rows ) then it adds BUT when second time clicked and the row exist it doesn’t add a new row and only plus one quantity each click in the column “Quantity “ ?